# Android JsonArray Retrurn and View with Table Layout

Tags: android, json, tablelayout

I would like to view JsonArray Response and view with Table Layout in android.

Json Response is like this!

```
[{"id":1,"name":"hot drink"},{"id":2,"name":"cold drink"},{"id":3,"name":"myanmar food"},{"id":4,"name":"thai food"}]
```

For My Result XML file , I wanna See Like this with `TableLayout`

```
ID          Name
1           Hot Drink
2           Cold Drink
3           Food
```

Comment: what xml file ? Also try to format your question a bit

Comment: Parse JSON response to some array, or list, and then loop through the  array to load the response in xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] id,name;

JSONArray jsonarrayobj = new JSONArray(yourjsonvalue);

id = new String[jsonarrayobj.length()];
name = new String[jsonarrayobj.length()];

for(int i=0;i<jsonarrayobj.length();i++){

JSONObject jobj = jsonarrayobj.getJSONObject(i);

id[i] = jobj.getString("id");
name[i] = jobj.getString("name");
}
```

> Now you'll have the values in the id and name arrays.
>
> Now with the help of [this](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/dynamic-tablelayout-in-android/) you can get the view as you said.